# iOS submit form return key

Tags: ios, objective-c, form-submit

fairly new to iOS programming. I want to be able to submit a form with the return key after the password has been entered. Right now i have a username and password text field. Once the client enters the password I want the enter key to be able to submit the form. I have a submit button to allow signing in, but I also want the return key to do the task as well. Any help would be great!
This is for iOS, object-c programming.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO @Srmuhs, you should show us your code. Without its hard to guess where your problems occur or what you tried so far. See [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle UITextFieldDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == ...your password field...) {
        //Your submit code goes here
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: dont forget to set the delegate for your textfield. good luck